# linkbuttons on mouse over becomes bigger and font bolded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, linkbutton

How can I make that when i pass the mouse over a ASPNET linkbutton it doesen't turn into a font bold?

[image]

```
a:hover{something here}
```

does not work

Comment: [What have you tried or found so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: check the linkbuttons `css` please...

Comment: You need to give the css of this button, or find them by your self using the browser debug tools and fix it.

Comment: I've been trying to change the css to all linkbuttons on my page but no succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is to add or remove attribute from the link button like

$('#linkbutton-id"').mouseover(function() {
  $('this').attr("font-weight","weight:bold")

});

$('#linkbutton-id"').mouseover(function() {
  $('this').removeAttr("font-weight")

});

you can use addClass or removeClass function of Jquery also, they provide you feature to add css class over element for any effect

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather prefer to use css so that all linkbuttons have the same style.